# Moq'n Complex Methods

Tags: unit-testing, moq, crm

I have inherited a mess of a code base and I have been asked to attempt to right effective "unit tests" and automated tests to support upcoming changes. We are using Crm 4.0. Here is an example of the code I am trying to Moq:

```
public static creditdebitcardEntity CreateCreditCardInstance(Transaction transaction, TransactionSet transactionSet, accountEntity stetyAccount)
    {
        try
        {
            //todo: check for existance
            creditdebitcardEntity stetyCard;
            ColumnSet customColumns = new ColumnSet();
            customColumns.Attributes = new string[]{creditdebitcardEntity.creditdebitcardidName,
                                                    creditdebitcardEntity.expirationmonthName,
                                                    creditdebitcardEntity.expirationyearName,
                                                    creditdebitcardEntity.reasonheldName,
                                                    creditdebitcardEntity.heldonName,
                                                    creditdebitcardEntity.statuscodeName};
            creditdebitcardEntity[] tempCard =
                creditdebitcardDal.GetCreditCardEntityByHashcode(transaction.CreditCards.CreditCardHash, customColumns);

            if (tempCard != null)
                return tempcard;
            else
                return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DirectiveExceptions.ReturnStagingException("CreditCardDirectives", "CreateCreditCardInstance", "An error occurred when trying to create a credit card transaction instance for folio " + transaction.SourceTransactionID + ". Contact a system administrator", ex, transaction.SourceTransactionKey);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

so my question is this; how do I mock out the call to the CreditDebitCardDal? I cannot make changes to the code base without having to go through a bunch of wickets. I can introduce new code with little effort, but modifying the existing code requires a lot of regression testing.

I do understand how to mock out the call to the static method and passing in the required objects is no issue at all either. I just don't want to rely on my SUT having a Crm database to ensure that the code is working. I am thinking that I could create an Interface to the Dal Class and then mock that interface, but wanted to see if there was a better way before I started down that road.

Thanks and let me know if I can provide any additional details.
Chuck

Answer (score 0):

I would mock out the parameters to start with. Extract an interface from Transaction, TransactionSet, accountEntity. From this you can then mock out the dependencies. You will have some more work to do but should be along the lines of below. The code below is just to show you, it is not tested or compiled

```
[TestFixture]
public class CreditDebitCardUnitTests
{

   private Mock<ITranscation> MockTransaction {get ; set;}
   private Mock<ITransactionSet> MockTransactionSet {get; set;}
   private Mock<IAccountEntity> MockAccountEntity {get; set;}

   [Setup]
    public void TestFixtureSetup()
    {
         MockTransaction = new Mock<ITransaction>();
         MockTransactionSet = new Mock<ITransactionSet>();
         MockAccountEntity  = new Mock<IAccountEntity>();



    }

   [Test]
   [Category("CreditCard tets")]
   public void VerfiyCreditDebitCardDal_GetCreditCardEntityByHashcode_Gets_Called
   {
      //Arrange
      ColumnSet customColumns = new ColumnSet();
        customColumns.Attributes = new string[]{creditdebitcardEntity.creditdebitcardidName,
                                                creditdebitcardEntity.expirationmonthName,
                                                creditdebitcardEntity.expirationyearName,
                                                creditdebitcardEntity.reasonheldName,
                                                creditdebitcardEntity.heldonName,
                                                creditdebitcardEntity.statuscodeName};

       MockTransaction.Setup(x => x.CreditCards.CreditCardHash).Returns(It.IsAny<Hash>)
      //Act
      creditdebitcardEntity[] tempCard =
            creditdebitcardDal.GetCreditCardEntityByHashcode(MockTransaction.ObjectCreditCards.CreditCardHash, customColumns  )
      //Assert

   }
}
```